# Telegram 2.1.7 launcher icon not showing up ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I installed the telegram-desktop from synaptic package manager. However, i am not able to see the launcher icon for it. Each time, i have to go to terminal and run telegram-desktop to make it work.

Attaching the screenshot. It would be nice if somebody can help.

[image]

Comment: By the way, which method fixed it? My answer had multiple parts

Comment: Thanks and wish you the same :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the desktop file is not executable.

Open a terminal, and run the command

```
chmod +x .local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop
```

You might have to logout and login for it to show up in the menu.

If it does not work, replace the contents of the file `.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop` (using the command `gedit .local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop`) with the following.

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Telegram Desktop
Comment=Official desktop version of Telegram messaging app
TryExec=telegram-desktop
Exec=telegram-desktop -- %u
Icon=telegram
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=TelegramDesktop
Type=Application
Categories=Chat;Network;InstantMessaging;Qt;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/tg;
Keywords=tg;chat;im;messaging;messenger;sms;tdesktop;
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
```

You might have to run `chmod +x .local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop`
once again.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop` and everything works fine. Must be left over from an older installation.